# How to list tables with suffix of dates?

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I need to fetch below kind of tables from DBC.tablesv.

Adom_test_20221114
Domtest_test_20221013
Etc........

Looking for a best suggestion. I appreciate if you could share me the query instead of any docs/websites

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Are you looking to list tables where the name ends in a date?

Comment: Yes, underscore date

Comment: How about: WHERE REGEXP_SIMILAR(TableName,'.*_\d{8}$')=1